Exceptionally slow when moving files within same server
We have a storage server that we are reorganizing. We created a new DFS shared folder located on the same server and I am trying to transfer files between the two shares. This is taking exceptionally longer than I would expect. Between when I logged off last night and when I left last night and signed on this morning only two files have completed, though these are very large compressed data files (.7z, 2-3 TB each). I would expect however that transferring files on the same system just requires remapping the location without actually transferring the data. Is that not the case? Is there a quicker way to do this transfer?
I'll note that I am an end user accessing this from a client computer and not an administrator logging in directly. I'll answer and look up any questions I can but may not know all of the info you need up front.

If the files are on the same server, and you are connected to the same server, do not use network shares or DFS to move files because then you put things over the network card which is limited by certain factors.
Always use local moving of files, so that the harddisk just has to update the file allocation table if the data remains on the same drive. Or at least transfer a lot faster if it goes from drive to drive.
EG:
✔ C:\ -> D:\
✖ \\Server\Share1 -> \\Server\Share2
If you RDP into the computer, but can't access the local drives, ask your system administrator to move the files for you.

I'll see if he can do this. I seem to remember him saying he didn't want to do it that way because then it would make his account the owner of all of the files. Does that seem normal to you?

Well the local move worked! And no issue with the file ownership changing so I'm not sure what the first admin was worried about.

Depends on how you move it. If the files are stored on FAT32 and are moved to NTFS, then yes, windows would assign ownership to the currently logged in account as it creates permissions. If you go from NTFS to NTFS, windows just copies the permissions and owner. If permission changes are made on a higher level, it may override your files at some point though.
